# copying data to excel using python (xlwt)

Tags: python, xlwt

I'm trying to copy data to an excel file using xlwt in a python code

```
 worksheet.write(globdat.cycle,1,fint)
```

globdat.cycle is a count. No problems there since it gets values 1, 2.... n in each iteration.

BUT

'fint' is a row vector with an unknown number of entries so I cannot exactly give the number of columns.

How can I be able to copy all the values in 'fint' to the excel file ?

If I had used Matlab I could have kept it as a ':" but I do not know how this is done in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `fint` is iterable, you could do something like this:

```
for i, j in enumerate(fint):
    worksheet.write(globdat.cycle, i, j)
```

Comment: Hey. Thank you so much for your reply. It worked a treat. But then I had issues with the allocation of cell space. So I changed into xlsx now it just keeps writing on the same row. Overlapping the previous data.

Comment: Using ```xlwt``` with a .xlsx file will never work because the module is designed only for .xls files.  If you need to work with .xlsx files, try using (```xlsxwriter```)[https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/].  Alternatively, post a new question with the complete error message and the code relavent to the message as well as what solutions you've tried